# Problema con bucles FOR

Tags: c, array, bucle-for

Estoy intentando simplificar el contenido de la función movimiento() a dos bucles, pero al hacerlo en bucles no me hace nada. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
int movimimiento(){
    mueve_servo(&patas[1][1], mov_home[1][1]);
    mueve_servo(&patas[1][2], mov_home[1][2]);
    mueve_servo(&patas[3][1], mov_home[3][1]);
    mueve_servo(&patas[3][2], mov_home[3][2]);
    mueve_servo(&patas[5][1], mov_home[5][1]);
    mueve_servo(&patas[5][2], mov_home[5][2]);

}
```

Mi duda es como puedo poner el contenido en forma de bucles para reducir código y sobre todo que tenga la misma funcionalidad. He hecho lo siguiente, pero no me hace nada:

```
int numero_patas[3] = {1, 3, 5};
int num_art[2] = {1, 2};

for(int pata = 0; pata < sizeof(numero_patas); pata++) {
    for(int art = 0; art < sizeof(num_art); art++) {
        mueve_servo(&patas[numero_patas[pata]][num_art[art]], mov_home[numero_patas[pata]][num_art[art]]);
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

Estas haciendo algo simple de una forma totalmente complicada.

No necesitas un array (y menos dos) para hacer ese for.

Solamente tenes que mover tus variables la cantidad de pasos necesarios, y cortar donde corresponde.

Seria algo asi:

```
for(int pata = 1; pata < 7; pata=pata+2) {
    for(int art = 1; art < 3; art++) {
        mueve_servo(&patas[pata][art], mov_home[pata][art]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te comento por aquí, las llamadas a patas y mov_home no se podría quitar porque son llamadas a los pines de la placa y a los valores de movimiento del servo. SoftPWM patas[6][3] ={{SoftPWM(coxa_1),SoftPWM(femur_1),SoftPWM(tibia_1)},{SoftPWM(coxa_2),SoftPWM(femur_2),SoftPWM(tibia_2)},{SoftPWM(coxa_3),SoftPWM(femur_3),SoftPWM(tibia_3)},{SoftPWM(coxa_4),SoftPWM(femur_4),SoftPWM(tibia_4)},{SoftPWM(coxa_5),SoftPWM(femur_5),SoftPWM(tibia_5)},{SoftPWM(coxa_6),SoftPWM(femur_6),SoftPWM(tibia_6)}};
 
int mov_home[6][3] = { {120,90,90}, {85,90,90}, {60,90,90}, {60,90,90}, {95,90,90}, {130,90,90}};

Comment: Lo único que podría cambiar serían los valores de dentro del array: mueve_servo(&patas[1][1], mov_home[1][1]); ¿se podría de alguna manera?

Comment: ahi edite la respuesta @jose. Lo principal era explicarte que tu for esta mal.

Comment: Y esta siguiente función como quedaría?                                        
      void avanza(){
    mueve_servo(&patas[1][SERVO_COX], mov_avanza[1 [SERVO_COX]); mueve_servo(&patas[3][SERVO_COX], mov_avanza[3][SERVO_COX]);
        mueve_servo(&patas[5][SERVO_COX], mov_avanza[5][SERVO_COX]);
        mueve_servo(&patas[0][SERVO_COX], mov_retrocede[0][SERVO_COX]);
        mueve_servo(&patas[2][SERVO_COX], mov_retrocede[2][SERVO_COX]);
        mueve_servo(&patas[4][SERVO_COX], mov_retrocede[4][SERVO_COX]);
}

Comment: @jose si los numeros son siempre simetricos, y siempre el mismo orden, vale mas que escribas las lineas de codigo y no te mezcles en tratar de hacer vectores y for...next que no sean logicos. No tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Pero es por simple simplificación, en este ultimo caso que te pongo SERVO_COX sería todos a 1

Comment: No estas simplificando nada. Solamente es menos codigo que se ve, pero eso no quiere decir que va a ser mas rapido. Y a veces, se entiende mas si esta todo bien descripto a que si esta todo complejizado porque "parece" que esta mas simplificado ;)